# Column 1 as the label and column 2 of the variables starts as column 1 in table in R

Tags: r

By executing read.table() function in R as below,

```
dat<-read.table("foo.txt",header=T)
dat
```

I receive the following output:

```
  Sizes Var1  Var2
1 Size1    2    5
2 Size2    6    4
3 Size3    1    8
```

However, the column 1 is "Sizes" instead of "Var1". I wish to have "Var1" starts as column 1 while keeping "Sizes" as the label. For example,

```
      Var1  Var2
Size1    2    5
Size2    6    4
Size3    1    8
```

How could I get it?

My apologies for confusing title as I couldn't think of a better way to describe what I want. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need rownames, You can use **row.names** in **read.table** like below:

```
read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
a b
           1 2
           3 4
           ", row.names=1)
```

If you put `row.names=2`, then column **b** would be taken as rownames, if it is NULL then it will put both **a** and **b** as column with default rownames as.numbers.

From the documentation of `?read.table` (row.names):

> a vector of row names. This can be a vector giving the actual row
>   names, or a single number giving the column of the table which
>   contains the row names, or character string giving the name of the
>   table column containing the row names
>
> If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than
>   the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the
>   row names. Otherwise if row.names is missing, the rows are numbered.
>
> Using row.names = NULL forces row numbering. Missing or NULL row.names
>   generate row names that are considered to be ‘automatic’

It will output like below:

```
  b
1 2
3 4
```